# pandas df.query() function with range()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use range(a,b) in a query call to a pandas dataframe, it's unsuccessful:

```
df.query('column_a in range(a,b))
```

Is there a solution to use range in a query call?

Answer (score 4):

Using range is not support. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval

A possible solution would be:

```
df.query("column_a >= a and column_a < b")
```